# DoCMD.RunSQL (UPDATE TABLE INCREASE VALUE POS)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I hope somebody can helping with this question.
I use bellow VBA code within an Access Database MdB.

But now i need to know how to update the column Pos with 1,2,3,4,5,
The default value is now for the column Pos zero.

Example Result:

[image]

I use the current script now but i don't know how to add the + 1 value per record.

```
Public Sub DoSQL()
 
    Dim SQL As String
    
    ' Here i want + 1 for the pos in every next record....

    SQL = "UPDATE TABLE SET Pos = 1 WHERE Box = 'UPDATE'"
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
     
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
SQL = "UPDATE TABLE SET Pos = Pos + 1 WHERE Box = 'UPDATE'"
```

If all *Pos* are zero, try this:

```
SQL = "UPDATE TABLE SET Pos = Id WHERE Box = 'UPDATE'"
```

If *Id* is not sequential, you can use one of the methods described here: [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. 

When i use "Pos + 1" then al select records (UPDATE) get the value 1. 
But i need 1 2 3 4 increment for every Pos per record. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: OK, so Pos holds zero only. Try some alternatives - see extended answer, please.

Comment: Oh sorry; i don't have the column with id numbers (type fault).. I have only the Pos column and the box column. Pos = Id is not working for me because i don't have the Id Column.

Comment: Then the simple method is to add the field `Id` as an _AutoNumber_ field, then run the update query. Or, if you don't delete records, rename `Id` to `Pos`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; But i cannot use the AutoNumber Field because i select records with the where Box column. the only option is the record id what is selected. Is there a way to use the records id as value for the pos? When i run the update sql statement i have records 1 t/m 4.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow - first a table, now a query/filter. You should rephrase your question with full information, representative sample data, and requested output. Again, study my link above, it has multiple methods for sequential numbering.